# Local Json object coming back as undefined

Tags: javascript, html, json, object, undefined

I am beginner trying to make a new image appear upon clicking the button. However, every time it is clicked. It says the src is undefined. I have tried having the images locally saved , putting an image address, I also renamed the object, but it is not working. For the purpose of testing it out I made all of my data the same. Any help, would be appreciated. Thank you!

```js
const url="http://localhost:3000"

fetch(url+"/photos")
.then((res)=>res.json())
.then((data)=>(data))



const loadButton = document.querySelector('#load_button');
loadButton.addEventListener('click', loadImages);


function loadImages(photos){
    const containerImages=document.querySelector('.container-new-images');

    // images.forEach(image =>{
     let pictures = document.createElement('img');
     pictures.src=photos.image;
     containerImages.append(pictures);

    // })
}
```

```
    {
    "photos" : [
{
    "id":1,
    "photographer":"Rémi Thorel",
    "username":"@RémiThorel",
    "image":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1617678151201-2596079f0b30?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=908&q=80"

},
{
    "id":2,
    "photographer":"Rémi Thorel",
    "username":"@RémiThorel",
    "image":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1617678151201-2596079f0b30?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=908&q=80"


},
{
    "id":3,
    "photographer":"Rémi Thorel",
    "username":"@RémiThorel",
    "image":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1617678151201-2596079f0b30?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=908&q=80"


},
{
    "id":4,
    "photographer":"Rémi Thorel",
    "username":"@RémiThorel",
    "image":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1617678151201-2596079f0b30?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=908&q=80"


},
{
    "id":5,
    "photographer":"Rémi Thorel",
    "username":"@RémiThorel",
    "image":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1617678151201-2596079f0b30?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=908&q=80"


},
{
    "id":6,
    "photographer":"Rémi Thorel",
    "username":"@RémiThorel",
    "image":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1617678151201-2596079f0b30?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=908&q=80"


},
{
    "id":7,
    "photographer":"Rémi Thorel",
    "username":"@RémiThorel",
    "image":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1617678151201-2596079f0b30?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=908&q=80"


},
{
    "id":8,
    "photographer":"Rémi Thorel",
    "username":"@RémiThorel",
    "image":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1617678151201-2596079f0b30?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=908&q=80"


},
{
    "id":9,
    "photographer":"Rémi Thorel",
    "username":"@RémiThorel",
    "image":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1617678151201-2596079f0b30?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=908&q=80"


},
{
    "id":10,
    "photographer":"Rémi Thorel",
    "username":"@RémiThorel",
    "image":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1617678151201-2596079f0b30?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=908&q=80"


},
{
    "id":11,
    "photographer":"Rémi Thorel",
    "username":"@RémiThorel",
    "image":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1617678151201-2596079f0b30?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=908&q=80"


},
{
    "id":12,
    "photographer":"Rémi Thorel",
    "username":"@RémiThorel",
    "image":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1617678151201-2596079f0b30?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=908&q=80"


}

]
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.0/css/line.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./nav.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./gallery.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./about.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./footer.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./credits.css">
    <script defer src="./index.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bebas Neue">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="top">
        <div class="nav_container">
          
            <nav class="desktop-nav">

        <ul class="nav_Links">
            <li><a href="index.html" class="bar">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html" class="bar">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html" class="bar">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="credit.html">Credits</a></li>
            <li><a href="connect.html" class="bar">Connect</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
        
    </div>
    </div>
     <nav class="mobile-nav">
        
            <button class="nav-mobile-btn"><img class='btnimg'src="menu-4-32.png" alt="hamburger icon"></i></button>
            <button class="nav-mobile-btn"><img class='btnclose'src="x-mark-32.png" alt="close icon"></i></button>
                 <ul class="mobile-nav-links">
                     <li><a href="index.html" class="mobile">Home</a></li>
                     <li><a href="gallery.html" class="mobile">Gallery</a></li>
                     <li><a href="about.html" class="mobile">About</a></li>
                     <li><a href="credit.html" class="mobile">Credits</a></li>
                     <li><a href="connect.html" class="mobile">Connect</a></li>
                 </ul>
             </nav>
         
    <header class="container_header">
    <h1>Gallery</h1>
    <h2> The Beauty Of The World Through The Lens</h2>
    <p class="gallery_description">
        All of these beautiful images belong to many talented photographers, that share
        their work on <i><a style="color:black"href="https://unsplash.com/">unsplash</a></i>. 
        Check out my credit page, where i share who each image is from and how you can message them if you
        are interested in their amazing work
    </p>

</header>

<section>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="image_container">
        <div class="image"><img id ="img1" src="./photo1.jpg" alt="man in fog" >
           <p class="credits">photo by</p></div>
        <div class="image"><img id ="img2" src="./photo2.jpg" alt="on the subway"></div>
       <div class="image"><img id ="img3" src="./photo12.jpg" alt="tacos"></div>
      
    
        <div class="image"><img id ="img4" src="./photo4.jpg" alt="flowers"><p id="description">blahhh</p></div>
        <div class="image"><img id="img5"src="./photo5.jpg" alt="sunset building"></div>
        <div class="image"><img id ="img8" src="./photo6.jpg" alt="mexico mi amor"></div>
     
            <div class="image"><img id="img9" src="./photo7.jpg" alt=""> </div>
            <div class="image"><img id="img11" src="./photo8.jpg" alt=""> </div>
            <div class="image"><img id="img12" src="./photo9.jpg" alt=""> </div>
        </div>
   


<div class="container-new-images">
    <div class="images">


        <div id="button_container">
            <button id="load_button">LOAD MORE</button>
           </div>
    </div>

</div>

    <div class="pop_up_image">
        <span>&times;</span>
        <img src="./photo7.jpg">
    

       


       
    </div>
</section>


    <section class="footer">
        <div class="footer_container">
           
     <br>
            <a id="linkedin" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/alejandra-landa-moya-aa2476109/"><img src="linkedin (1).png" alt="linkedin icon"></a>
        <a id="github" href="https://github.com/aleLanda-rq"><img src="github (3).png" alt="github logo"></a>
        <div id="links_footer">
       <a class="footer_credits" hred="index.html">Home</a>
        <a class="footer_credits"href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
        <a class="footer_credits"href="about.html">About</a>
        <a class="footer_credits" href="credit.html">Credits</a>
        <a class="footer_credits"href="connect.html">Connect</a>
  
    <!-- <a href="https://iconscout.com/icons/linkedin" target="_blank">LinkedIn Logo Icon</a> by <a href="https://iconscout.com/contributors/ma-lourdes-suello" target="_blank">Ma. Lourdes Suello</a> -->
    <!-- <a href="https://iconscout.com/icons/social" target="_blank">Github Logo Icon</a> by <a href="https://iconscout.com/contributors/pocike" target="_blank">Those Icons</a> -->
    <!-- <a href="https://iconscout.com/icons/github" target="_blank">Github Logo Icon</a> by <a href="https://iconscout.com/contributors/roundicons-com" target="_blank">Roundicons.com</a> -->
</div>
</div>
         
    
       
</section>
       
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want load something from an api, you need to write the `fetch` function inside the loading function. in your case, your function will be like this:

```
const url="http://localhost:3000"

const loadButton = document.querySelector('#load_button');
loadButton.addEventListener('click', loadImages);

function loadImages(){
    const containerImages=document.querySelector('.container-new-images');
    fetch(url+"/photos")
    .then((res)=>res.json())
    .then((data)=>{
        data.photos.forEach(p =>{
            let picture = document.createElement('img');
            picture.src = p.image;
            containerImages.append(pictures);
        });
    });
}
```